# grep && awk combination result in bash

Tags: bash, shell, grep, cut

why `ping -c 1 google.com  | grep "bytes from" | cut -d = -f 1` returns `64 bytes from 216.58.216.206: icmp_seq` and not `0 ttl`? I expect that `-f 1` return `0 ttl`.

Answer (score 3):

You can get it all using `awk` and avoid `grep`, `cut`:

```
ping -c 1 google.com | awk -F= '/bytes from/{print $2}'
0 ttl
```

btw your command should be:

```
ping -c 1 google.com  | grep "bytes from" | cut -d = -f 2
```

to get the same output as `0 ttl` is field #2

Answer (score 1):

```
ping -c 1 google.com | grep "bytes from" | cut -d = -f2
0 ttl
```

If you wish to get till 0 ttl then

```
ping -c 1 google.com | grep "bytes from" | cut -d = -f1-2
64 bytes from yyz08s14-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.2.142): icmp_seq=0 ttl
```